# Set backgound image on fixed height of website

Tags: html, css

On my landing page i want to set a background image that appears at exact section. My design is currently boxed, so I set up the background image to body, because I want the image to appear on whole width (not just inside my set box width).

```
body {
  background-image: url("bg-image.png") !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-origin: padding-box;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-size: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1; 
  background-position: 0% 70%;  
}
```

Now is the image appearing on  70% of my screen size. How can I set it up it will always appear on position 70% of my entire front page?

If I am setting it up like background-position: 0px 1200px; its not working and its also not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this code :

```
body{
  background: url(image/bg.jpg) no-repeat center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Let me know if it's what you want.

Comment: No, i want the background to appear on exact position on the page. Let say i scroll down the page and on the position 2500px from top the background image appears. Is this even possible? Its an image height of 300px and takes the whole width of the screen size. Thank you.

Comment: if you want this background on a wrap box you set up this box outside a box parent which have a width: if the parent width is directly body and set at width:100%, you have to apply the cover rule and background on the box.If you want an example let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
    background: white url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size: cover;
}
```